# How to select Severity for a diagnostic fault?

Tags: diagnostics

When creating a new diagnostic fault, how should we select Severity level?
And what are difference between different level?

```
enum Severity {
  UNKNOWN = 0;
  INFO = 1;
  WARNING = 2;
  ERROR = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ERROR: Error should be used when a fault condition directly affects the ability of component to meet its design requirements. This typically means the fault also has 'triggers_nogo=true' or some other direct constraint reaction or serves as a direct input to a Fault Aggregator that has a direct constraint reaction.

WARNING: Warning should be used when a fault condition indicates a degraded performance that still meets its design requirements.

INFO: Info faults can be used whenever a condition is present that is of particular interest but does not represent any noticeable degraded performance of the component.